# How to convert this code to scala (using adal to generate Azure AD token)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-active-directory, adal

I am currently working on a Scala code that can establish a connection to an SQL server database using AD token.

There are too little documentation on the subject online so I tries to work on it using python. Now it is working, I am looking to convert my code to Scala.

Here is the python script:

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials("https://database.windows.net/", CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
access_token = token["accessToken"]

df= spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", URL) \
        .option("dbtable", "tab1") \
        .option("accessToken", access_token) \
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
        .load()

df.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Java code that you can use as a base, using the [acquireToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.authenticationcontext.acquiretoken?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_aad_adal4j_AuthenticationContext_acquireToken_final_String_final_ClientCredential_final_AuthenticationCallback_) function:

```java
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;

...

String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<org-uuid>";
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential("sp-client-id", "sp-client-secret");
AuthenticationResult result = context.acquireToken("resource_id", credential, null).get();
// get token
String token = result.getAccessToken()
```

P.S. But really, ADAL's usage isn't recommended anymore, it's better to use [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java) instead (here is the [migration guide](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/migrate-adal-msal-java.md))

Comment: How can I exploit the result please ? I did println(result) and I got com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult@c65a3855
How can I actually use the token ?

Comment: let me update answer. You get token as `result.getAccessToken()`

Answer (score 0):

The Scala code for the MSAL implementation would be:

```
%scala

import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j._
import java.util.Collections
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

var accessToken = ""
val tenantId =  dbutils.secrets.get(scope="defaultScope",key="TenantId") 
val authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId
val resourceAppIdURI = "https://database.windows.net/.default"

val ServicePrincipalId =dbutils.secrets.get(scope = secretScope, key =     DatabricksSpnId)
val ServicePrincipalPwd =dbutils.secrets.get(scope = secretScope, key =     DatabricksSpnSecret)

val ClientCred = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(ServicePrincipalId,
  ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(ServicePrincipalPwd)).authority(author    ity).build()
val clientCredentialParam =     ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(resourceAppIdURI)).bui    ld()

println(">>> Acquiring Access Token ..")
accessToken =     ClientCred.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam).get().accessToken()
println("accessToken ---->> " + accessToken)

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"                   -> "sebichondodbserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"          -> "testdb",
  "dbTable"               -> "[dbo].[BuildVersion]",
  "accessToken"           -> accessToken,
  "hostNameInCertificate" -> "*.database.windows.net",
  "encrypt"               -> "true"
))

val collection = sqlContext.read.sqlDB(config)
collection.show()
```

More information on this implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/idaceappdev/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal)